# JQuery different methods for adding classes

Tags: jquery, class, addclass

I have seen a few different methods for adding classes to dynamically created elements using JQuery.

I'm most familiar with

```
$("<div />").addClass("class1 class2");
```

however I have seen a lot of

```
$("<div />", {
  class : "class1 class2"
});
```

When I test out the second method in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/qx32V/5/) I can see both class1 and class2 are applied.

however, when applied to what [i'm working on](http://rlemon.com/test.html)

```
// this does not work
var b = $("<div id='tweetBox' />", {
    class : "triangle-right right"
});

// this works
var b = $("<div id='tweetBox' />").addClass("triangle-right right");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't mix and match.

try:

```
var b = $("<div />", {
    id: "tweetBox",
    class : "triangle-right right"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this does not work
var b = $("<div id='tweetBox' />", {
    class : "triangle-right right"
});
```

Doesn't work because there is an attribute on the element you are creating.

```
This will work
var b = $("<div />", {
    id: 'tweetBox',
    class : "triangle-right right"
});
```